# Nikon D750 - Histogram while shooting?

Tags: histogram, preview, nikon-d750

Is it possible to view the histogram of a scene either through the viewfinder or in live view prior to releasing the shutter in Nikon D750?

I can see it during review - but then need the extra step of deleting the photo if the histogram is all thrown off. Ideally being able to see it before clicking will be terrific.

Is this possible in D750? I can't find the setting as anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't view histogram via viewfinder, this is DSLR and you see via lens.

In live view mode you can press Info button several times and on one of the views you will see histogram.

Comment: Thank you Romeo. Is there a way to make the screen with histogram the default screen?, instead of having to press info. repeatedly?

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG, unfortunately i did not found in D750 menus something which can permit you to customize Info screens